# Is there a more concise way to write this PostgreSQL aggregate window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, weather

I can calculate the rainfall since 9am for a site using a series of 10 minute records as a cumulative value, however the nested SQL seems verbose and I'd like to make it more concise for future maintainability. I could use a CTE which might make it a little cleaner, but wondering if there's an approach to get this in a single call with the SUM & PARTITION BY and not use my current CASE approach?

The following postgres query calculates the rainfall since 9am using 10 minute values. Firstly I add a field determining whether the day is before or after 9am - in this case I want to include 9am and zero minutes as part of the previous days "rainfall since 9am" value, but anything after i.e. 9:01 should be the point at which the running total reset. I know I'm using 10 minute records in this example, but I do want do this down to the minute as there will be other sites reporting at minutely frequency but this example site is just reporting at 10 minutes.

```sql
SELECT
    site_name,
    date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart' AS date_time_local,
    precip_10min,
    precip_since_9am,
    day_9am_val,
    SUM(precip_10min) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY site_name, day_9am_val ORDER BY date_time_utc) AS precip_since_9am_cal
FROM
    (
        SELECT *,
            CASE
                WHEN DATE_PART('hour', date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart') > 9 THEN (date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart')::date
                WHEN DATE_PART('hour', date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart') < 9 THEN ((date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart')::date - INTERVAL '1 day')::date
                WHEN DATE_PART('minutes', date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart') > 0 THEN (date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart')::date
                ELSE ((date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart')::date - INTERVAL '1 day')::date
            END AS day_9am_val
        FROM
            temp_export
    ) tbl

ORDER BY
    site_name, date_time_utc DESC
```

The expected value is provided as *precip_since_9am* and the calculated value (which should match) is *precip_since_9am_cal*. The *day_9am_val* is not required, it's just illustrating how I tackled partioning the days for a 9am cutoff. I've placed small subset of the data in SQL fiddle [here](https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler?id=90f5ccf0-f509-4887-8964-f0364d0e4d8c), but also show some example rows below:

| site_name | date_time_local | precip_10min | precip_since_9am | day_9am_val | precip_since_9am_cal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sitea | 2024-01-18 17:00:00 | 0.2 | 10.8 | 2024-01-18 | 10.8 |
| sitea | 2024-01-18 16:50:00 | 0.4 | 10.6 | 2024-01-18 | 10.6 |
| sitea | 2024-01-18 16:40:00 | 0.2 | 10.2 | 2024-01-18 | 10.2 |
| sitea | 2024-01-18 16:30:00 | 0.2 | 10 | 2024-01-18 | 10.0 |
| sitea | 2024-01-18 16:20:00 | 0.4 | 9.8 | 2024-01-18 | 9.8 |

Comment: Hi - it would be helpful if the sample data in your question included rows for at least 2 days and at times before 9am, so that you are showing the possible use cases. Also, I'm not sure you need 4 lines in your case statement - isn't the logic just if the minutes are <= 9 then date - 1 else date i.e. one logic statement and an ELSE?

Comment: Hi @NickW the data in the sql fiddle does have that data (there's just a limit 10 rows at the end that can be removed). I tried putting a second example table in the question originally but markdown refused to format it as a table like the first one, no idea why.  Do you mean hours <= 9? I can't do that because 9am needs to be date -1 but 9.01am needs to be date.

Comment: But you're right I can cast to time and bring it from 4 lines to 2:                 WHEN (date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart')::time > '9:00' THEN (date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart')::date
                ELSE ((date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart')::date - INTERVAL '1 day')::date

Comment: As the only thing you’re doing in the sub-select is the case statement I'd dump the sub-select and do it all in one select statement

Comment: thank you! I should have just tried putting the case into the partition by, I'd wrongly assumed that wasn't possible. Did you want to add as answer? If not I'll post the final SQL without the sub select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting to remove the sub-select per NickW's suggestion and include the case by directly in the partioning fields:

```sql
SELECT
    site_name,
    date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart'                                 AS date_time_local,
    precip_10min,
    precip_since_9am,
    SUM(precip_10min) OVER (PARTITION BY site_name, (CASE
                                                       WHEN (date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart')::time > '9:00'
                                                       THEN (date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart')::date
                                                       ELSE ((date_time_utc AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Hobart')::date - INTERVAL '1 day')::date
                                                       END) ORDER BY date_time_utc) AS precip_since_9am_calc
FROM
    temp_export

ORDER BY
    site_name, date_time_utc DESC
```